# How to use formulas like in Excel in the iForels database?

Tags: database, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, iforels

I try to configure the formula (SUM) field in the iForels database.
But they don't have chess kind of cells: like A1, C7, etc.

My formulas in Excel look like this `=SUM(A1:A800)`and `=(A1+B1*C1/D1)`.

iForels is one of the best productivity tools I've tried, but it's useless  if simple formulas will not work.

Thank you for any help!

PS: I tried to copy formulas from Excel into my iForels application. I expect it will work in the same way as in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  iForels "formula" feature supports JS syntax as well as Excel/Google Spreadsheet's predefined functions. Actualy,  you almost answered your question. The iForels is a database and Excel is spreadsheet: just use column/feature name instead of code like a cell coordinate (A:1...).

Your `=(A1+B1*C1/D1)` formula would look like `@A+@B*@C/@D`. A, B, C, D - could be any name of the column/feature. For example `@price+@qty`.

You CAN modify the name of column any time, and formula would still work perfectly.

Another important nuance: because iForels is a database it automatically understands which row do you mean, and you don't have to specify the number of row, like A1, A2, etc.

You could also use functions like `=SUM(A1, B1, F1)`. Just use correct database columns: `SUM(@A,@B,@F)`. Also  `= symbol` is not required in iForels.

If you need the "totals" for some specific columns just click on the bottom of the column and choose 'SUM'.

There are variety of precalculated totals, such as Average, Number of records, Standart Diviation and many more.
Be aware that totals are sensitive to the filters.

It calculates datasets which matches your filters request. If you'd like to see total sum for all records you have, just make sure there are no filters applied.

In case If you need filter from time to time, DONT delete it, just disable filter by clicking the icon near "term-condition" item.

iForels is much easier than Excel :)

Hope it helps!